# Unable To Import CSV file Python

Tags: python, csv

I wanna run this code that my friend helped me construct but I keep getting this error below. I tried moving both the file of the code and the excel files around but still, it couldn't find/open the code. What do I need to do?

```
import csv
import pandas
from textblob import TextBlob

#checking total pos, neg and neu REVIEWS

f = open('BirchboxCaff.csv', encoding='utf8')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

pos=0
neg=0
neu=0

w = open('BirchboxCaffNEW.csv','a', newline='',encoding='utf8')
csv_w = csv.writer(w)
for row in csv_f:
    blob =TextBlob(row[1])
    value = blob.sentiment.polarity
    row.append(value)
    csv_w.writerow(row)


'''
    print(blob.sentiment.polarity)
    if ((blob.sentiment.polarity)>0):
        pos = pos+1
    if ((blob.sentiment.polarity)==0):
        neu = neu+1
    if ((blob.sentiment.polarity)<0):
        neg = neg+1


print(pos," ", neu, " ", neg)
'''
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/Sara Jitkresorn/Downloads/Sentiment01.py", line 7, in 
>      f = open('BirchboxCaff.csv', encoding='utf8')
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'BirchboxCaff.csv'

Comment: use os.path.exists('BirchboxCaff.csv')  to make a conditional statement. Most probably, you're having problem because of relative paths. Try getting file in the current directory where main file is.

Comment: Sorry. I do not quite get what you said. So I have to add a line of code `os.path.exists('BirchboxCaff.csv')` ? Also what do you mean by your last sentence? Sorry I have very little knowledge of python/programming.

Comment: thats nothing but checking whether given path exists or not, and using if-else statements to work around. os is a module you can import with `import os` statement. Check whether file is actually in current directory or not.

Comment: @SaraJitkresorn Read through [`[python] FileNotFoundError`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+FileNotFoundError+relative+path)